# Best method of cooking an Almond PearTart decoration/top layer

Tags: decorating

I followed this recipe yesterday because I made an pear tart for today. I still have some time to do the top layer but the recipe did not explain anything after that (or I missed it): **Pears, milk, flour, almond, sugar, eggs and salt AND 2 PEARS FOR THE TOP LAYER** (*If you want the quantity in grams, I can also put it*). The texture of it before baking was very similar to a cheese cake (and so does now after baking). **It doesn't have any kind of crust underneath it.**

This is how the top layer and cake should look like (The source is the recipe, a screenshot, I'm sorry I cannot do more).

[image: Almond Pear Tart]

Only two things come to mind, by seeing in the ingredients **2 pears for decorating**:

- Decorating regularly adding on top honey or sugar/cinnamon and burn it a little bit
- Doing an pear compote (might be too sweet for the smooth sweet taste of this almond/peartart?)

The top layer of my cake looks brownish, so that might be the brownish color of the recipe picture... But I'm really not sure.

**EDIT**:
RECIPE::

- 500g peeled and cored pears
- 250g whole or semi milk
- 200g all purpose flour
- 100g ground almonds
- 180g sugar
- 3 large eggs
- 2 big pears for decorating
- a pinch of salt

> Mix all the ingredients in a blender until the batter is homogenic and pour it in a 23cm springform mould. Bake for 50-55 minutes at 180 degrees Celsius with top and bottom heat. If it is a bit raw (check with a toothpick as usual) you can leave it outside, so the residual heat will finish it

Comment: Why do you call it an apple tart? It seems to be a pear tart based on the ingredients.

Comment: Sorry, I regularly confuse those two words, since always... My bad, edited! @Johanna

Comment: Without having seen the original recipe: Are you sure that the pears weren’t supposed to go on top of the cheesecake layer *before baking*? You could also link to the recipe for more details?

Comment: Yes, that is my worry. The recipe did not say anything. So my question is more related on what woudl the best option be for the top layer (the cake is already baked!) @Stephie

Comment: Can you include the recipe please?

Comment: Edited and added! Sorry! I also posted an answer with the recipe of the syrup I made afterwards!  @Kat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, maybe I did not explain properly what my problem was in the question, in which case I apologise. An already baked pear-almond cake recipe did not specify what to do with the top layer, so I baked it regularly without adding regular pear on top of the batter before baking it.

As a result, I thought of making an **improvised** pear syrup

- 2 pears
- 150g sugar
- 1/2 ts of vanilla extract (depending on your liking)
- 75ml water
- Cinnamon

Boil the water with sugar and vanilla extract. Add the pears once everything has integrated. For the pears,  I peeled, cored and cut them in thin slices and added them to the pot. Finally, add that to a tray/mold, add cinnamon to your liking on top, and bake for half an hour at 175 degrees Celsius.

Let it cool. What I did: brush the liquid of the syrup into the cake , add the pears in your decorating liking, and brush again a bit on top.

**Final result:**

[image: Syrup]

[image]

**Final advice after seeing it:**

I think the best would have been to add the raw pears on top of the batter once it's on the tray/mold before baking it. I did not do it, so in order to fix it:

1. Adding less water might make the syrup more dense, which would be nice in this case
2. The green mould, as you can see, is quite small. I think the bigger and more spread the pears are, the better the final result will be for them
3. If you have flavourless gelatine, definetly it'd have been a good idea to add it on top of the pears. I didn't have so, bad luck.
4. BURNING with a kitchen torch on top of the syrup (or adding a bit more sugar and then burning) would give it a very nice texture and flavour in my opinon.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would prepare it by slicing the pears and placing them decoratively on top of the batter in some pattern. Then I would add an egg wash to help it brown nicely during the bake. A pear compote would, in my opinion, not add enough texture to the finished product. If you use whole pear slices, you will get a bit of a contrast between the smooth custard of the tart and the (hopefully) slightly firm pear slices on top.

Comment: That would work, but as I mentioned, the cake is already baked, because the recipe did not say anything else! Just "two pears for decorating", but nothing related to when to place them or how. At the moment I did a pear syrup, currently in the oven. I will thinly cut the top layer (so both layers will stick)!

Comment: I added another answer! I'd like you to see what you think! I guess there is no definite answer to the question but yours was definetly nice as well and would have solved it if I hadn't baked the cake before! I'll mark it as an answer if you like it more then the one I posted, as both would solve the problem!